# Node declaring express many files difference?

Tags: node.js, express

my English not very well but

My question is:

in this file

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(require('./routes/index.js'));
app.listen(3000);
```

routes/index

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get(....
 
module.exports = app;
```

because I have to declare app again, is it necessary to create or instantiate express multiple times in multiple files?

what is the difference between app = express() in index.js   and   app = express() in routes/index.js

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you are trying to implement routing in your Node.js application. If I am right then correct code of

**routes/index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', ...

module.exports = router;
```

As you can see in above code that you don’t need to reinitialize the app again into the index.js. Instead you have to initialize the router.